# how to get POST DATA in backend

Tags: c#

I am using AJAX to POST data. In my Javascript, I generate some JSON data and post it to my backend. The problem is how do I get the POST JSON data in c# web form?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) collection. This retrieves the values of form elements posted to the HTTP request body, with a form using the POST method.

If it is an ASP.NET MVC project, MVC can do model binding with your input JSON data so that you get the posted data as the properties of your View Model object.

Comment: i do check with the request.form but seems like not having the posted JSON data